# Minifined moment.js file with specific locale using Gulp and require.js?

Tags: requirejs, gulp, locale, momentjs

When you get `moment.js` library from Bower, there are these minified packages:

- `moment.min.js` - without locales
- `moment-with-locales.min.js` - with all locales included (still quite big file)

My goal is to create ONE minified `moment.js` file that would include my needed locales using `Gulp`. Here is my Gulp code:

```
var config = {
    //...
    moment: 'bower_components/moment/moment.js',
    momentLt: 'bower_components/moment/locale/lt.js',
}

gulp.task('vendor', ['clean-vendor', 'bower'], function () {        
    gulp.src([config.moment, config.momentLt]).
        pipe(concat('moment-custom.js')).
        pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'})).
        pipe(uglify()).
        pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/moment'));

});
```

File is combined and minified successfully. When I try to load this file using `require.js`, it is loaded successfully

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "vendor/jquery/jquery.min",
        "moment": "vendor/moment/moment-custom.min",
    }
});
```

*(TypeScript)*

```
import $ = require("jquery");
import moment = require("moment");

moment;
```

*(JavaScript)*

```
define(["require", "jquery", "moment"], function (require, $, moment) {
        moment;
}
```

But locale is not working:

```
moment().locale(); => en
moment().locale('lt');
moment().locale(); => en
```

My considerations:

- Is this my problem `moment-custom.min.js` file?
- Do I load this file correctly using `require`?
- Should I declare another `require` module for locale exclusively?